# How to make reCAPTCHA work with a ValidationGroup in ASP.Net (captcha)

Tags: asp.net, captcha, recaptcha

I am using the ASP.Net plugin and control provided by [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net). I can successfully get the control to work if the submit button on the web form is not in a validationgroup. There is no validationgroup attribute for the reCAPTCHA control.

Has anybody had any success with this or any solutions to get the reCAPTCHA control to work when there is a validationgroup on the web form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reCAPTCHA ASP.NET plug-in is written to be backward-compatible with ASP.NET 1.1, which means the `ValidationGroup` concept (which is new in ASP.NET 2.0) is not supported. But the plug-in comes with [downloadable source code](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:aspnetlib-Latest), so you can modify it yourself to support `ValidationGroup`.

In ASP.NET 2.0, [validators should inherit from `BaseValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator_methods.aspx) and implement `IValidator`, which means you should change the RecaptchaControl type to inherit from `BaseValidator` instead of `WebControl`. You will then have to modify the code a bit to implement all methods and properties defined in `BaseValidator`. Then you can use this new control on your page instead, which now supports `ValidationGroup`.

Comment: Hi bzlm. I've done the above, but have two problems:
1) BaseValidator also requires you to implement the abstract EvaluateIsValid() method (reutrning the IsValid property with it doesn't work).
2) The reCaptcha control then needs the ControlToValidate property filled.
Can you help with any of those? Thanks.

Comment: I commented out the IValidator implementation that is giving by the reCAPTCHA plugin, and pushed that logic into the EvaluateIsValid() method. I also bypassed the ControlToValidate property in code since it doesn't seem to apply in this scenario.

One other point to realize is that you should handle situations where validate is called more than once on the page. You need to ensure that you don't actually call the reCAPTCHA API twice as this will invalidate the control. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, would it be possible to get a bit more info on how to do this? Or has someone already got a completed project they can share?

Comment: @TimS, [did you try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231344/how-to-make-recaptcha-work-with-a-validationgroup-in-asp-net-captcha/656888#656888)?

Answer (score 7):

Thought I'd just expand on the comments by a few others with some working code...

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="RecaptchaControl" runat="server" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="RecaptchaValidator" runat="server" OnServerValidate="RecaptchaValidator_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Recaptcha input invalid." ValidationGroup="SomeValidationGroup" />
```

And code behind...

```
protected void RecaptchaValidator_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    this.RecaptchaControl.Validate();
    e.IsValid = this.RecaptchaControl.IsValid;
}
```

Can anyone think of a simpler way of doing it? Kudos to Vidalik for the thoughts about using OnServerValidate.

Answer (score 5):

You can add CustomValidator, implement OnServerValidate that would validate the ReCAPTCHA data. CustomValidator can be assigned to any ValidatorGroup.

Comment: Nice solution. You just need to check recaptcha.IsValid in your OnServerValidate method then. Very simple!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...

1. Add a custom validator with the correct validation group.
2. Its its ServerValidate method call..

   ```
    recaptcha.Validate();
   ```
3. Then check as follows before your main processing...

   if (Page.IsValid && recaptcha.IsValid)
   {
   respose.write("valid");
   }

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231344/how-to-make-recaptcha-work-with-a-validationgroup-in-asp-net-captcha/656888#656888

Answer (score 1):

[RemotecUk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169640/remotecuk)'s suggestion worked for me without adding custom validator.

```
protected void button_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    recaptcha.Validate();
    if(!Page.IsValid && recaptcha.IsValid){
        lblError.Text = "Please check your captcha entry";
    } else {
        //do your thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do client-side required validation and without altering the reCaptcha source code, I added a CustomValidator to my form and created a JavaScript function to validate the input text field.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="reqRecaptcha" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateRecaptcha" Text="Required"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

To find out the `ID` of the generated input field I looked at the source code of the page and noticed that the input field was always`recaptcha_response_field`. (Please correct me if I am wrong) Knowing this, I was able to create the JavaScript (using JQuery and a custom function to check validity of a control).

```
    function validateRecaptcha(sender, args) {
        args.IsValid = isFieldValid("input[id$='recaptcha_response_field']");
    }
```

NOTE: If the developers change the output of the reCaptcha control, you may not be aware of the change resulting in the validator seizing to work.

Comment: `isFieldValid("input[id$='recaptcha_response_field']"); ` can also be `isFieldValid("#recaptcha_response_field");`. My original reference is a standard I have so that I can easily create CustomValidators for server controls.

Answer (score 0):

See ReCaptchaImage and ReCaptchaValidator controls being part of Altairis Web UI Toolkit: http://altairiswebui.codeplex.com/

It's open source set of web components, containing quite decent and ASP.NET standards-compliant (if I may say it being the author :-) implementation of ReCaptcha for Web Forms.